# Gitlab CI: Why does the same job have different results when re-running it?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab CI job that used to work, but now it doesn't.

First time: https://gitlab.com/T-vK/rpi-rt-kernel/-/jobs/51703707
Second time: https://gitlab.com/T-vK/rpi-rt-kernel/-/jobs/51949626

The docker image is exactly the same. $CI_COMMIT_TAG was set to 4.14 in both cases. But the second time it fails at: `git pull origin rpi-$CI_COMMIT_TAG.y`.
Saying `*** Please tell me who you are.`.

Why would this happen? I mean the git version must be the same because it's the same docker image.

This is the relevant part of the ci script:

```
- export KERNEL=kernel7
- cd /tools
- git pull
- cd /linux
- git checkout rpi-$CI_COMMIT_TAG.y
- git pull origin rpi-$CI_COMMIT_TAG.y # suddenly fails...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your local branch can't be fast-forwarded to the branch on origin so git attempts a merge. A merge creates a commit so it requires a user to be configured and it fails. You can try `git checkout origin/branch` instead.